# Solving 5 Linear Equations in Python

Tags: python, equation-solving

I've tried using matrices, and it has failed. I've looked at external modules and external programs, but none of it has worked. If someone could share some tips or code that would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Could you share the equations in question? (It is possible they are inconsistent - ie have no solution - or not fully constrained - more than one solution).

Comment: They're arbitrary. Mainly I'm solving for the coefficients of an equation like so: ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + c  
  
so for example: 
a + b + c + d + e = 1  
16a + 8b + 4c + 2d + e = 2  
81a + 27b + 9c + 3d + e = 3  
256a + 64b + 16c + 4d + e = 4  
625a + 125b + 25c + 5d + e = 8

They are consistant and fully constrained

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy
import scipy.linalg

m = numpy.matrix([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [16, 8, 4, 2, 1],
    [81, 27, 9, 3, 1],
    [256, 64, 16, 4, 1],
    [625, 125, 25, 5, 1]
])

res = numpy.matrix([[1],[2],[3],[4],[8]])

print scipy.linalg.solve(m, res)
```

returns

```
[[ 0.125]
 [-1.25 ]
 [ 4.375]
 [-5.25 ]
 [ 3.   ]]
```

(your solution coefficients for a,b,c,d,e)

Comment: Thanks so much!! Not just a way to do it, an example of how it's done. Good job.

Comment: I just realized why I hate using external modules... It's so rare that it goes smoothly

Comment: Is it possible to solve this within numpy? I CAN NOT get scipy to run on this computer... :/

Comment: Oh, yes you can. Just replace scipy.linalg.solve(m, res) with numpy.linalg.solve(m, res).

Comment: Okay, now how do I assign one of those list items to a variable? I keep getting [[0.125]]...

Comment: @JShoe: `sol = numpy.linalg.solve(m, res)` `a,b,c,d,e = sol.A1`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say the matrix methods don't work. That's the standard way of solving these types of problems.

From a linear algebra standpoint, solving 5 linear equations is trivial. It can be solved using any number of methods. You can use [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), finding the [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix), [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), etc.

If you're lazy, you can always resort to libraries. [Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) and [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) can both solve linear equations with ease.

Comment: The answer just didn't come out right. I don't know why. I know that matrices should normally work, and that it's standard, I'm just having difficulty implementing it.

Comment: @JShoe: That sounds like the perfect candidate for a question on SO. You should solve the problem if possible, not work around it!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're using matrices in a wrong way.

Matrices are just like lists within lists.

```
[[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

The aforementioned code would make a list that you can access like `mylist[y][x]` as the axes are swapped.

Comment: I definitely know how to make a matrix. Thanks though.

Comment: @JShoe Why the downvote? I thought maybe you were using it wrong, as the y and x are flipped. Also, I'm not really sure why you are using Numpy or Scipy, as it seems kind of overkill for what you are trying to do.